# How to remove the Error of "no resource found that matches android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarsize"

Tags: java, android

Hi guys i am making an application which has the Tabhost/Tabtoolbar on the top and it also has the viewerpage below of it. Am facing Error in my `toolbar_layout.xml` file

The error is showing in the line `android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarsize` with cause:

> no resource found that matches the given name

This Error i am getting each time when I create a new Fragment java class and Fragment xml file in the application

Below i have my code. Plz help me out this to fix the Error and Am using Android 5.1 for version for doing this in my Android studio

Thanks in advance

Toolbar layout xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarsize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    app:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Main xml file

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.mohammadzakriya.tabhost2.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            ></android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainAcivity java file

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar =(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        tabLayout =(TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        viewPager =(ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new HomeFragment(),"Home");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new Database(),"Database");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new contact(),"contact");
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }
}
```

ViewPage Adapter

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String>  tabTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addFragments(Fragment fragments,String titles){
        this.fragments.add(fragments);
        this.tabTitles.add(titles);
    }



    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm){

        super(fm);
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabTitles.get(position);
    }
}
```

my build.gradle(Module: app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mohammadzakriya.tabhost2"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
}
```

Comment: ___`Java !== JavaScript`___

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarsize"
```

To:

```
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

Note that is `actionBarSize` with capital `S`

Comment: Thanks due to this minor mistake was facing the Error.The changes which u mentioned actually worked and got Executed the project thanks

Comment: @MohammadZakriya Good to know!!! Glad I could help you. I just kindly request to accept the answer since it fixed your issue... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:minHeight="?android:actionBarSize"`.

Comment: In your code you are using `?attr/actionBarsize` which is different from `?android:actionBarSize`. Try changing to `?android:actionBarSize` and test then.

Comment: ya am using ?attr/actionBarsize. And have appiled the edit which u had mentioned but the error seems to be still existing

Comment: Take care of case sensitivity as well, check you namespace to be this `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`. And clean-> rebuild your project.